# .map is not a function when fetching data from API reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, map-function

I'm using an API to fetch data. When I console.log my data, it shows as an array. But when I try to map over it to get the data to display, it tells me that .map is not a function. I created a custom useFetch hook and then I'm importing it into a separate component. Here's my code and a screenshot of the console.log:

useFetch.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function useFetch(url) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw Error("Sorry, couldn't fetch data for this resource!")
                }
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(responseData => {
                setData(responseData)
                setIsLoading(false)
                setError(null)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                setIsLoading(false)
                setError(error.message)
            })
    }, [url])

    return { data, isLoading, error }
}

export default useFetch
```

List.js

```
import React from 'react'
import useFetch from './useFetch'

function PrizeList2017() {
    const { data } = useFetch('http://api.nobelprize.org/v1/prize.json?year=2017&yearTo=2017')

    return (
        <div className="prize-list-2017-container">
            <h1>2017</h1>
            {data.map(prize => (
                <div key={prize.id}>
                    <h2>{prize.category}</h2>
                </div>
            ))}
            {console.log(data)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default PrizeList2017
```

console.log

[console.log info image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCafi.png)

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data is not present yep when you try to do the map so do:

```
  {data && data.prizes && data.prizes.map(prize => (
```

Comment: Hi there! Yes, I tried that already and was still getting the same error.

Comment: i didn't see the console log, data is actually an object and data.prizes an array

Comment: Okay, I figured so but the console.log was saying array! I'm still unsure of how to extract the data from the object!

Comment: Try to map with data.prizes, it should be, i edited my message

Comment: Oh thank you so much this worked! Life saver!!!

Comment: This is because you define initially data as null so it can't access the data.prizes when it's null, you need to check that data isn't null to do the map

Comment: How come it wouldn't work with just {data && data.prizes.map(prize => (? Just want to really understand why adding the data.prizes in the middle worked!

Comment: I really appreciate all your help, thank you SO much!

Comment: You welcome, mark as good answer if it works for you